# Splitting a single Python process into chunks for memory isses?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, memory-management

Per an answer to another question I've posted, I'm running the following Python code:

```
diff = np.abs(mat0[:,None]-mat1)
```

Where `mat0` is a 866,000 x 3 matrix, and `mat1` is a 925,000 x 3 size matrix.

I have ~74 GB of RAM, and still get an out of memory error.

I don't know how broadcasting works in Numpy, but is there a way to split this process up into chunks so that it doesn't run out of memory?

Comment: Even if you chunk this, you're still trying to compute several terabytes of values. That's going to be slow. Are you sure this is the best way to do what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to find where these matrices overlap within a certain tolerance. This was my original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513204/finding-intersection-of-two-matrices-in-python-within-a-tolerance/33514917#33514917

Comment: The answer you got just makes the loops faster by pushing them into C code. It doesn't help with the algorithmic inefficiency. You may want to consider tools like sorting or kd-trees to reduce the number of points that need to be compared with each other.